# User Settings for background image

Tags: vb.net, image, application-settings

Can I use application settings to save a background image?
For example, I want to make an CPanel witch have an option for upload background image for program. I want that after save, that image to be background image.

I have 2 options for this but I don't know codes:
1. Upload image to resources and in code, I use setting name instead of photo name
2. After upload into CPanel, that image will overwritte the current image with same name. For exemple I have in Resources folder a photo named logo.png. With code, I put this photo to be background. After Upload an image, that image should overwritte current logo.png so then program will start, he will start with current logo.png.
But for second option I have an additional question. If I will put external image into PictureBox and set PictureBox Background to Stretch, that photo will be Stretch or will be with normal dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I mean then you set background to a form. Can I somehow make an button witch will change that background and save him? Like If I press change and save, second background (last) will remain until he will be changed? If I change background and close and open app, I will get initial background.